# Merging CSV files : Appending instead of merging

Tags: bash, shell, unix, csv, merge

So basically i want to merge a couple of CSV files. Im using the following script to do that :

```
paste -d , *.csv > final.txt
```

However this has worked for me in the past but this time it doesn't work. It appends the data next to each other as opposed to below each other. For instance two files that contain records in the following format

```
CreatedAt   ID
Mon Jul 07 20:43:47 +0000 2014  4.86249E+17
Mon Jul 07 19:58:29 +0000 2014  4.86238E+17
Mon Jul 07 19:42:33 +0000 2014  4.86234E+17
```

When merged give

```
CreatedAt   ID CreatedAt    ID
Mon Jul 07 20:43:47 +0000 2014  4.86249E+17 Mon Jul 07 18:25:53 +0000 2014  4.86215E+17
Mon Jul 07 19:58:29 +0000 2014  4.86238E+17 Mon Jul 07 17:19:18 +0000 2014  4.86198E+17
Mon Jul 07 19:42:33 +0000 2014  4.86234E+17 Mon Jul 07 15:45:13 +0000 2014  4.86174E+17
                                            Mon Jul 07 15:34:13 +0000 2014  4.86176E+17
```

Would anyone know what the reason behind this is? Or what i can do to force merge below records?

Comment: it seems like one of your .csv file has more# of lines that other .csv file. Not sure from where you are getting the space. paste command uses "," to separate the entries.

Comment: Do you mean that you did `cat file*.csv > final.csv` . That would give you records "below each other". Good luck.

Comment: What is the purpose of `-d ,`?

Comment: How should the result look like? Do you mean `join`?

Comment: @ArunSangal : Yes but the count shouldnt matter for a join should it? Cyrus - Yes i mean join. The purpose of -d , was to separate it by comma. Also the Answer below worked.

Comment: Its not possible to use paste and get file below each other. That's something cat command or tail -n +N filename can do like Hastur mentioned below.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Assuming that all the csv files have the same format and all start with the same header,
you can write a little script as the following to **append all files in only one** and **to take only one time the header**.

```
#!/bin/bash
OutFileName="X.csv"                       # Fix the output name
i=0                                       # Reset a counter
for filename in ./*.csv; do 
 if [ "$filename"  != "$OutFileName" ] ;      # Avoid recursion 
 then 
   if [[ $i -eq 0 ]] ; then 
      head -1  "$filename" >   "$OutFileName" # Copy header if it is the first file
   fi
   tail -n +2  "$filename" >>  "$OutFileName" # Append from the 2nd line each file
   i=$(( $i + 1 ))                            # Increase the counter
 fi
done
```

Notes:

- The `head -1` or `head -n 1` command print the first line of a file (the head).
- The `tail -n +2` prints the tail of a file starting from the lines number 2 (`+2`)
- Test `[ ... ]` is used to exclude the output file from the input list.
- The **output file is rewritten** each time.
- The command `cat a.csv b.csv > X.csv` can be simply used to append a.csv and b csv in a single file (but you copy 2 times the header).

The `paste` command pastes the files one on a side of the other. If a file has white spaces as lines you can obtain the output that you reported above.
The use of `-d ,` asks to `paste command` to define fields separated by a comma `,`, but  this is not the case for the format of the files you reported above.

The `cat` command instead concatenates files and prints on the standard output, that means it writes one file after the other.

Refer to `man head` or `man tail` for the syntax of the single options (some version allows `head -1` other instead `head -n 1`)...

Comment: I read now what he meant. Btw, you can put that increment to "i" variable within IF statement instead within the loop.

Comment: @ArunSangal It's right. My error, I copied an old version. If the increment is outside the `if` block and the file of output is the first of the list, you will never have the header in the output file.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks for sharing

Comment: Noticed a small corner case issue: it breaks if filenames contain spaces. Can be fixed with adding some quotes: `"$filename"`.

Comment: @Jonik Right and proper, thanks; fixed. It is devious to peek around a corner ... As you do, you risk to spot another one: better to put `"` even to `$OutFileName` `;-)`

Answer (score 2):

Alternative simple answer, this as combine_csv.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
{ head -n 1 $1 && tail -q -n +2 $*; }
```

can be used like this:

```sh
pattern="my*filenames*.csv"
combine_csv.sh ${pattern} > result.csv
```

Comment: Nice, `&` should be `&&` though

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much @wahwahwah.
I used your script to make *nautilus-action*, but it work correctly only with this changes:

```
#!/bin/bash

for last; do true; done

OutFileName=$last/RESULT_`date +"%d-%m-%Y"`.csv                       # Fix the output name

i=0                                       # Reset a counter
for filename in "$last/"*".csv"; do

 if [ "$filename" != "$OutFileName" ] ;      # Avoid recursion 
 then 
   if [[ $i -eq 0 ]] ; then 
      head -1  "$filename" > "$OutFileName" # Copy header if it is the first file
   fi
   tail -n +2  "$filename" >> "$OutFileName" # Append from the 2nd line each file
   i=$(( $i + 1 ))                        # Increase the counter
 fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I concatenate CSV files that have the same columns:

```
(head -qn 1 *.csv | head -n 1; tail -qn +2 *.csv) >combined.csv
```

Save time by calling `head` on any of the files specifically:

```
(head -n 1 first.csv; tail -n +2 *.csv) >combined.csv
```

No scripting or funky `awk` necessary!

Answer (score 0):

Give [***joinem***](https://github.com/mmore500/joinem) a try, available via PyPi: `python3 -m pip install joinem`.

*joinem* provides a CLI for fast, flexbile concatenation of tabular data using [polars](https://pola.rs).
I/O is *lazily streamed* in order to give good performance when **working with numerous, large files**.

### Example Usage

Pass input files via stdin and output file as an argument.

```bash
ls -1 path/to/*.csv | python3 -m joinem out.parquet
```

You can add the `--progress` flag to get a progress.

### Further Information

*joinem* is also compatible with parquet, JSON, and feather file types.
See the project's [README](https://github.com/mmore500/joinem/) for more usage examples and a full command-line interface API listing.

*disclosure*: I am the library author of *joinem*.