# how to effectively determine the significant differences between two .csv files

Tags: csv, dictionary, d3.js, visualization

Is there a way to quickly determine why two `.csv` files that should be interchangeable are not?

Something like a diff/validation type mechanism for critical assessment.

I have a d3.js map which I'm trying to make visualize some data, when I use my [initial data set](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/s-matthew-english/BitcoinSavingsBank/master/ANCIENT_JobPosts_15_11_2015_12632.csv) it works perfectly, but on the [new set I created](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/s-matthew-english/BitcoinSavingsBank/master/X.csv) it crashes with a `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error.

My initial guess is that:

- since the headers are named differently- maybe that's the issue --> but they were generated in order to be compatible with one another so I'm doubting this.
- the new one is a bit bigger than the old one, could that be it?

Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with web development nor working with large*ish* data sets of this nature- I've been looking around for a solution but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Impossible to tell what's going on without seeing your code. I notice that the new CSV has spaces before the commas (which will become part of the name of the field in the code), so this may be something to have a look at.

Comment: what's the way to remove that? with regex? `perl` or something?

Comment: Again, it really depends on what you're doing with it. You could be handling this correctly or it couldn't matter at all.

Comment: I'm trying to render it suitable for visualization with [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/s-matthew-english/BitcoinSavingsBank/master/index.html)

Comment: Does it open in Excel or LibreOffice? It's CSV with headers, so I think it should.

Comment: Well you're using different names in your new CSV and the code is referencing some names that don't exist. I would fix that first.

Comment: but even when I put the names from the old file it doesn't work

Comment: @BryanT sort of- it said something like `data could not be loaded completely because the max number of characters per cell was exceeded`

Comment: Sounds like you are exceeding the limits of the visualization tool.
I copied&pasted about 20 lines' worth into a CSV file and it opened with OfficeLibre. The headers, as some one suspected, had a leading space.

I assume the files are from different projects, but the tool should work on both?

Comment: that is true- to make the new data set I combined it together from many files with [this bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641948/merging-csv-files-appending-instead-of-merging/24643455)- the one from the first answer- should I not have done that? do I need to remove that leading space?

Comment: I think the space in the headers is the least of the problems :-(
I have produced CSV files and XML that open as a spread sheet, but I don't know d3.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to approach the task would be to normalize your two CSV files (e.g. by using one of the csv2tsv tools out there) and then compare them.   Assuming the fields are in the same order, the comparison could be done in a bash environment like so:

```
 diff <(sort FILE1.tsv) <(sort FILE2.tsv)
```

(Or you might want to use the -bw options: diff -bw ....)

If you're lucky, you might be able to gain some insight into the differences by skipping the normalization step and simply running:

```
 diff <(sort FILE1.csv) <(sort FILE2.csv)
```

If the columns are not in the same order, then you'd obviously have to re-order them before performing the `diff`.  How best to do that would partly depend on the some details (about the CSV files) which you haven't provided.

Answer (score 1):

For a high-level view of the CSV (or normalized) files, looking at a histogram of the number of fields is often useful, as indeed is the case with your ANCIENT and X .csv files.  After converting them to .tsv, the histograms of the number of fields are clearly different.  Below, they are displayed horizontally in a format that need not be described here in detail, except to note that each line of the histogram shows the value, its frequency, and a horizontal bar that reflects that frequency:

```
$ awk -F\\t '{print NF}' X.tsv | sort -n | histogram
9 57260 ##########################################################
10 3080 ===============================
11 2090 =====================
12 1103 ===========
13 632 =======
14 304 ------------------------------
15 69 ------
16 116 -----------
17 42 ----
18 17 -
19 10 -
21 2 

$ awk -F\\t '{print NF}' ANCIENT*.tsv | sort -n | histogram
88 12633 #############
```

It is thus evident that the ANCIENT file is a well-formed, rectangular CSV file, whereas the X file has a different format.  It looks like the X file has a hierarchical layout, with "," as the field-separator, and "|" as the subfield separator.