# Merging CSV files based on filename filter

Tags: bash, csv

I'm trying to develop a bash script which filters csv files (generated every hour) for a day before and merge them into a single CSV file. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24643455/4099228) script seems to do the job for me, except that I'm trying to filter files based on their filenames.

There would be 24 files for each day in the directory, and I need to filter out these files based on their name format:

```
foofoo_2017052101502.csv

foofoo_2017052104502.csv

foofoo_2017052104503.csv

foofoo_2017052204501.csv

foofoo_2017052204504.csv
```

Here, I need to filter out for May 21, 2017. So my output CSV files must have the first three `.csv` files.

What should I add in the script for this filter?

Comment: Why not `cat foofoo_20170521*.csv > combined_20170521.csv`?

Comment: Can you  please accept the answer if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script will calculate the previous day yyyymmdd and use that value in the grep to automatically filter out all the file names generated the previous day.

For MacOS

```
dt=`date -j -v-1d +%Y%m%d`
echo $dt
OutputFiles=`ls | grep foofoo_${dt}`
```

For Linux

```
dt=`date -d "yesterday" +%Y%m%d`
echo $dt
OutputFiles=`ls | grep foofoo_${dt}`
```

These commands when added to the script mentioned will filter the file names for the previous day based upon the current time stamp.

Comment: What would be var2 in this case?

Comment: Good job on offering difference between the various `date` implementation depending on OS.

Comment: Thanks David C Rankin

Answer (score 1):

You can let `bash` do the filtering for you using [globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html), for example to list only files with date `May 21, 2017` you could use:

```
for filename in foofoo_20170521*.csv; do...
```

If you want to be able to call your script with an argument specifying the date to have more flexibility, you can use:

```
for filename in "foofoo_${1}*.csv"; do...
```

And then call your script with the date that you want to filter as an argument:

```
./your_script 20170521
```

And as @David C. Rankin mention in the comments, a very practical way to do it would be to concatenate all the files from the date you want into one csv that you would then use in your script:

```
cat foofoo_20170521*.csv > combined_20170521.csv
```

Comment: It also seems `cat` and *redirection* should be mentioned as well. (see comment to original question)

Comment: @DavidC.RankinThat's a very clever way to go. I updated my answer to include it.

Comment: `:)` yes, every once in a while, `cat` can actually be used for its intended purpose.